# how to change/ update starting characters of image path with new values

Tags: mysql, string

I have a table like this:

```
CREATE TABLE user_post (
  id int(30) ,
  user_id  int(11),
  text     mediumtext,
  image_path    varchar(4000) ,
  video_path      varchar(4000) ,
  created_date   timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL,
)
```

In this table we are storing image paths. Earlier we did'nt use CDN so our image path looked like this:

```
62197/Files/1582028253362.jpg
```

but now after using CDN, image path got changed and it looks like this:

```
https://s3-**********-1.amazonaws.com//abccdn/1582285090974.jpg
```

Now I want to change old image path, it should start with `https://`. I dont want to change manually image by image.

Is there any script?

Answer (score 0):

Sure you can update like:

```
SET @var_starts_with := 'https://';
UPDATE user_post
SET image_path := CONCAT(@var_starts_with, image_path)
WHERE image_path NOT LIKE CONCAT(@var_starts_with, '%')
;
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can use a query to update these values.

First you need some logic to convert values like `62197/Files/1582028253362.jpg` to values like `1582028253362.jpg`

Try using [SUBSTRING_INDEX()](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/string-functions.html#function_substring-index),something like this:

```
SELECT SUBSTRING_INDEX(image_path, '/', -1)
```

Run this on some of your data to convince yourself works.

Then do an UPDATE operation something like this.

```
UPDATE user_post 
   SET image_path = CONCAT(
        'https://s3-**********-1.amazonaws.com//abccdn/',
        SUBSTRING_INDEX(image_path, '/', -1)) 
 WHERE image_path NOT LIKE 'https://s3-%'
```

Notice that your old paths start with numbers like `62197/Files ...` The logic I have given you eliminates those numbers. That may or may not be correct for your situation: you should check.

One other thing to consider.  If you can, change the SELECT query you use to retrieve these `image_path` values so it returns paths to your CDN.  **Leave the `image_path` values in your table unchanged**, and manipulate them when you retrieve them. Then, if something in your CDN rig changes, you can change just the SELECT query.  A good way to do this might be to create a view, and use it when retrieving records.  Like this:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW user_post_cdn AS
SELECT id, user_id, text, 
       CONCAT('https://s3-**********-1.amazonaws.com//abccdn/', 
       SUBSTRING_INDEX(image_path, '/', -1)) image_path,
       video_path, created_date
  FROM user_post;
```

Then, when you need your cdn paths from your data base, you say something like this.

```
  SELECT * FROM user_post_cdn WHERE id = whatever;
```

This way

- you don't run the risk of corrupting your image_path data by updating it.
- if something changes in your CDN setup, you can just change the view definition and everything will keep working.